# List changed listeners

Tags: dart, flutter

i have a listview builder in flutter which is used to load a images when i remove a item i want to set listener for my listview that data has changed.
this is complete code this class is used for create a image style.

How can i solve hwn i click iconbutton i want to remove a item from list,
onw this is its removing when i press another button or something else

```
   class Users extends StatefulWidget
   {
    final   List image;
    final File imageURL;
  const  Users  ({Key key, this.imageURL,this.image}) : super(key: key);
 @override
 UserWidgets createState() => UserWidgets();
     }

 class UserWidgets extends State<Users>
  {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context)
  {
   VideoPlayerController playerController;
  VoidCallback listener;
   Widget play=new Icon(Icons.play_arrow);
  Widget pause=new Icon(Icons.pause);

  return new Container(
  height: 200.0,
  child: Stack(
     children: <Widget>[
        widget.imageURL.toString().contains(".jpg") ||widget.imageURL.toString().contains(".png") ||
           widget.imageURL.toString().contains(".jpeg") ?
        new Container(

       child: new Card(
      child: new Column(
      children: <Widget>[
      new GestureDetector(
                  onTap: ()
                        {
                        Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) =>   VideoApp(file: widget.imageURL,)
                          ),
                          );

                  },
            child:
                new  Image.file(widget.imageURL
                  ,fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  height: 200.0,
                  width: 150.0,

                       ),

                      )
                  ],
                  )
                  ),
              ): widget.imageURL.toString().contains(".mp4") ||widget.imageURL.toString().contains(".3gp") ?
              new Container(
                  height: 100.0,
                   child: AspectRatio(aspectRatio: 10/6,
                        child: GestureDetector(
                    onTap: ()
                  {
                         Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) =>  VideoApp(file: widget.imageURL,)
                    ),
                      );
                      },
                    child:
                      VideoPlayer(playerController = VideoPlayerController.file (widget.imageURL)
                    ..addListener(listener)
                      ..setVolume(1.0)
                        ..initialize()
                          ,
                            )
                                )
                            )
                          ): new
                          Container(),
                    new  Positioned(
                      child:
                        IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.remove_circle),
                        color: Colors.black,

                        onPressed : ()
                        {

                          setState(() {
                            widget.image.remove(widget.imageURL);
                            print("helo");
                          });
                        }
                        )
                      ,
                      top: 0.0,
                      right: 0.0,
                    )
                    ],
                  ),
                   );

                    }
                   }
```

now i need to know that what is equivalent to notifdatasetchanged().

Comment: if your listview builder is in the same widget as youe `setState` call, it will be rebuild. Can you post the code with the listview build so we can help you ?

Comment: i have listview in another class this is used for craete image

Comment: you have differents methods to propagate an event from a child widget to the top of you widget tree, the simplest is to use callback method from your parent to the child, but you can implement more powerful way to do it => http://fluttersamples.com